# How to run php in a java web application project in NetBeans

Tags: php, javascript, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I have a java web application created in NetBeans from 'File-->New Project-->Java Web-->Web Application'.
 I have Tomcat as the server. In my computer I can run php without any problem in a NetBeans php project, or in XAMPP.
But I want to run php commands in a java web application project. I tried by adding this code to index.jsp file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo 'php code here'; ?>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**It doesn't print 'php code here' string but print 'Hello World!' string**.
I tried renaming file name **index.jsp** to **index.php** (And also change the name in web.xml file). But it still gives me the same output

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Use `<?php ?>` tags instead of `<? ?>` tags. The parser may be confused.

Comment: And make sure your server is set up to interpret `.jsp` pages as "may contain PHP code".

Comment: sorry it was a mistake. It is <?php ?>.I changed it.but same result. What do you mean by "And make sure your server is set up to interpret .jsp pages as "may contain PHP code"

Comment: please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Apache configuration (httpd.conf). On the line that contains "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php", add .jsp to the end

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .jsp
```

And whatever other pages you want to be interpreted using PHP (.html, .htm, etc.).

Comment: it still doesn't work. There wasn't "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php" in my httpd.conf file. I added it as "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .jsp". then restart the server. but still doesn't work

Comment: @Roshanck Is php installed on your machine?

Comment: I think so. I can run php netbeans projects.I can run .php files in XAMPP server. that means I have php installed in my machine right? :)

Comment: What happens when you navigate to a locally hosted php page in your browser?

Comment: It display the output. As a example if i have a file name index.php and <?php echo 'php code here'; ?> inside the index.php file. When I navigate to http://localhost/index.php file, it display 'php code here' as the output

Comment: OK, so PHP is working. If the `httpd.conf` file you edited *didn't* have an `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` line, then that was the wrong `httpd.conf` file. Search your file structure for others.

Comment: I couldn't find any file from httpd.conf name. I could fine a file name'httpd-xampp.conf' which has 'AddType text/html .php .phps'. I added your code bellow that one and restart the server. but still the same result. doesn't work

Comment: @Roshanck That's all the troubleshooting I can think of :-(

Comment: when I run the netbeans web application the link in the url is 'http://localhost:8080/'. but in XAMPP it is 'http://localhost/'. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Roshanck Could be. They're listening on different ports (`localhost` is port 80, `localhost:8080` is port 8080), which means different servers are processing the files. Make sure the Tomcat server also serves .jsp files as PHP.

Comment: How can I do this 'Make sure the Tomcat server also serves .jsp files as PHP'

Comment: @Roshanck Google? Honestly I don't know. You're running two different servers which is causing some confusion (on both ends of this conversation, I imagine). I'm not even 100% sure it's a Tomcat issue. Whichever server is listening on port 8080 needs to serve .jsp as "possible" php files, similar to how I have described above.

Comment: OK thanks for the help :) I have one last question. Can you please tell me is it possible to do this?(thing I have mentioned in the question) Have you ever try to run php code in a java web application and make it work. If so I can fully concentrate on this problem and try to solve this.

Comment: @Roshanck Then again, as Yogi Berra once said, *"In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is."*